# Why does Hubble's showcase image contain a waveform when zoomed out?

Tags: waves

Why does Hubble's showcase image contain a waveform when zoomed out?

Is there any explanation for this? Is it the way the image has been mapped?

Image from Hubble showcase:
[image]

Image of a sine wave for comparison: 
[image]

[Hubble showcase on google/sky](https://www.google.com/sky/)

```
edit:
```

The wave is much easier to see if you toggle Infrared. Here is a screenshot with infrared on:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is an [Equirectangular Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) of the full [celestial sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_sphere). At the [Hubble showcase on google/sky](https://www.google.com/sky/) website, it provides both [Right Ascension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_ascension) coordinates (Specified in Hours, Minutes and Seconds, East-to-West on the Sphere, horizontal across the image) and  [Declination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declination) coordinates (specified in positive and negative degrees, North and South on the sphere,  vertical across the image) in the lower left.

The curve you're seeing that resembles a sine wave is the dust and stars of the Milky Way around the sky. The Milky Way's plane is tilted at an angle of about 60° to the Celestial Equator, which is why it dips above and below the center of the image. 24 hours of Right Ascension is equivalent to 360°, which is why the image repeats.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't contain a sine-wave.

If you look more closely at the image (and adjust the contrast), it's apparent that it is the result of stitching together separate images.

[image]

Comment: That's very obvious once you point it out. There are at least four copies. Why ever would that have been done?

Comment: I don't mean that part, wait, i'll edit a photo with a red line for the wave as well. But FYI I didn't notice that part of the image either so that's interesting too.

Comment: Edited - I don't know about you but it looks pretty wavy.

Comment: @RobbyReindeer You're right; there are sine waves if you zoom out more. But notice that the star patterns are identical in each cycle. This wouldn't happen, except through some quirk of their photo-viewer. The image no doubt covers a limited area, and just repeats itself if you try to look outside that area.

Comment: Looks to be the Milky Way, represented on an equirectangular projection of the celestial sphere, repeated a little over twice horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

The images would look that way if the hubble telescope orbits the earth at an incline. its view of the cosmos would then sweep up and down during its orbit. Furthermore, on successive orbits it will see the same stuff and a continuous record of its imagery would exhibit a repeat. These effects would have to be processed out of the imagery.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same reason that a flat, rectangular map of the Earth with the regions of day and night drawn on it, shows a "waveform".

The reason for this is that, in both cases, what you are seeing is a projection of a figure which exists on the surface of a sphere onto a flat map. In the case of the Earth, the sphere is obvious, in the case of *this*, however, the sphere is the "**view sphere**" or "**sky ball**" surrounding the Hubble Space Telescope: that is, the omnidirectional field of vision in all directions around it, Earth not included.

In each case, the figure is approximately a "great circle" - a straight line on the surface of the sphere. Because of the projection, however, such great circles become distorted into waveform-like shapes.

The "waveform" you see in the day/night map is the "terminator", or line of twilight, splitting the sunlit and dark sides of the Earth.

The "waveform" you see in your picture? It's **the Milky Way Galaxy's disc,** giving out radiation all across the electromagnetic spectrum. Since we are more or less fully immersed in the disc, it is effectively a straight line on our field of view, and hence taking the field of view as a sphere, thus a great circle, and hence upon mapping, undergoes an analogous transformation.